# Crash closing app after using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter-canvas

I'm getting a messy crash trying to close my python tkinter app (on ubuntu) after I have shown and closed a matplotlib plot. I am just closing the window using the 'x'.

```
invalid command name "140146113720200poll"
while executing
```

"140146113720200poll"
    ("after" script)

I clearly haven't closed something down properly, I found a couple of places saying a should close the figure on windows close, but figure has no close method. What should I do to properly release the resources I am using?

```
def plotit(self):
    if self.gdata is None:
        return

    if self.plotframe is None:
        self.plotframe = tkinter.Toplevel()
        self.plotframe.title('graphy stuff')

    self.plotfig = matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.plotfig, master=self.plotframe)
    ax = Axes3D(self.plotfig)
    ax.scatter(self.gdata[0],self.gdata[1],self.gdata[2],marker='o',s=1.3)

    canvas.show()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self.plotframe)
    toolbar.update()
    canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)
```

I tried setting up a tkinter close action on the window, but that doesn't help either.

Comment: Do not mix `pyplot` (which maintains all sort of state) with your own embedding in a tk GUI.  There is probably a race condition where _too many_ things are trying to tear the gui components down an exit.  See http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html